# The ReachableAddresses version of FascistFirewall

Tags: configuration

Is the following the equivalent of using `FascistFirewall 1`?

```
ReachableAddresses accept *:80
ReachableAddresses accept *:443
```

I ask this because it seems that [`FascistFirewall`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) will someday be deprecated (like `FirewallPorts` is) for the more versatile and less-provocatively named `ReachableAddresses`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there are any plans to deprecate [FascistFirewall](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).  At least the manpage does not say it is, unlike FirewallPorts.

And yes, that's exactly the equivalent if you haven't also set FirewallPorts.  In fact, it's how FascistFirewall is [implemented](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.17-rc:/src/or/config.c#l2549).

Maybe the log messages should be slightly change to not imply FascistFirewall is going away.