# Using entry nodes with specific ports

Tags: guard-node

Is there any way to tell the Tor daemon on my computer to only pick entry nodes with specific TCP ports? It seems like our ISP has started blocking Tor communication on its usual ports (443, 9001, etc). Once it finds a node with POP3 port 110 open - things finally start working. Telnetting to port 443 or 9001 of the failing node doesn't block and expects user input as any open port would - therefore some more sophisticated blocking is taking place.

Comment: The answer was very simple:  FascistFirewall 1
FirewallPorts 80,110 and that's it

Answer (score 2):

As you already wrote in your comment you can set `FascistFirewall 1` in your `torrc`. Tor will then use the ports 80 and 443 for outgoing connections to the first node.

The options `FirewallPorts` is marked as deprecated in the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en). So don't use this option. But you can use `ReachableAddresses` (see [The ReachableAddresses version of FascistFirewall](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/265/88) for details).